# Jtable will not save data of the cell when editing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have JTable that has a column editable. It should get Integer values and update table. But when I edit a cell and go to another cell, the data will erase and goes back to null but the program does not throw any exceptions. How can I fix it?

```
public class FoodListPanel extends JPanel{
JTable jTable;
FoodTableModel fm;

public FoodListPanel() {

    try {
         fm = new FoodTableModel(FoodDAO.getAllFoodsFromDB(), new ArrayList<Integer>());

        jTable = new JTable(fm) {

            public boolean isCellEditable(int data, int columns) {
               if(columns<5){
                   return false;
               }
               else if(columns ==5){
                   return true;
               }
                else if(columns ==6){

                  if(getValueAt(data, 5)==Boolean.FALSE){
                      return false;
                  }
                   else {
                      return true;
                  }
               }
                else{
                   return true;
               }
            }

            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int data, int columns) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(r, data, columns);
                return c;
            }


        };


        jTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(650, 420));
        jTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);

        add(jScrollPane);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class FoodTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    protected String[] cols = {"نام‌غذا", "دسته‌بندی", "قیمت", "توضیحات", "عکس" , "تعداد"};
    protected Class[] colClasses = {String.class, Integer.class, String.class, String.class,
    JLabel.class, Integer.class};
    ArrayList<Food> al;
    ArrayList<Integer> vals;
    public FoodTableModel(ArrayList<Food> foods, ArrayList<Integer> val) {
        al = new ArrayList<Food>();
        al.addAll(foods);


        vals = new ArrayList<Integer>(al.size());

        vals.addAll(val);

    }


    ////// TODO: 8/20/16 make dynamic from DB
    public int getColumnCount (){return cols.length;}
    public int getRowCount (){return al.size();}
    public String getColumnName(int col) { return cols[col]; }
    public Class getColumnClass(int col) { return colClasses[col]; }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){
        switch (col) {

            case 0:
                return al.get(row).getName();
            case 1:
                return al.get(row).getType();
            case 2:
                return al.get(row).getPrice();
            case 3:
                return al.get(row).getDiscreption();
            case 5:
                if(vals.size()>= al.size()) return vals.get(row);

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    ////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066012/index-out-of-bound-exception-when-setting-value-to-jtable
    public void setValueAt(Object vlaue, int row, int column){
       if (column==6){
            this.vals.set(row, (Integer)vlaue);
        }
        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();

    }

    /*public void setCols(String[] columns){
        cols = columns;
    }
    public void setClasses(Class[] classes){
        colClasses = classes;
    }*/
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask a new question without responding to answers in your [previous recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39066012/522444). Not good.

Answer (score 3):

> the data will erase and goes back to null

Your `getValuaAt(..)` and `setValueAt()` methods are out of sync.

In the `setValueAt()` you only save the data for column 6.

In the `getValueAt()` you only return the data for columns 0-5 and return null for column 6.

You need to fix the `getValueAt(...)` method to return the actual data, not null.

Also, the `setValueAt(...)` method should only invoke the `fireTableCellUpdated(...)` method not the fireTableDataChanged(...) method.

Comment: One plus, but fyi, he is asking a new question without responding to a [previous recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39066012/522444). Not good.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks for the heads up. I see the OP was last seen an hour after the answer was posted. I guess they have no intention to respond to this question either.